# In F#, how to change a property of a property within a record (Syntax?)

Tags: f#

Lets assume I have a record like:

```
 type Page = { footersize: Size }
```

what is the correct syntax to change **only** the Height of the footersize:

```
 { page with footersize = ??? }
```

TIA

Edit#1:  "Size" is the size of a FrameworkElement, i.e.,
Size is in the .Net world as Size(width,height) and is a structure, not record.  As tried below,
this does NOT work:

```
{p with footersize = {p.footersize with Height = 96 * 0.5}}
```

*Error: This expression was expected to have type 'Size' but here as type Page.*

Comment: What's the definition of `Size`?

Comment: Assuming `Size` is also a record; and `Height` is an `int`, the built-in way it to write `{page with footersize = {page.footersize with Height = 10}}`. If you are doing this kind of nested updating a lot you could also use a Lens abstraction (for example, the one from [FSharpPlus](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/lens.html))

Comment: @Asti  Size, as in .Net WPF, is 
Size(Double, Double) 
Initializes a new instance of the Size structure and assigns it an initial width and height.

Comment: @Mankarse -- oops, did not work.  Please see added information. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most direct way is to copy-update the whole object:

```
let page' =
    { page with
        FooterSize = Size(page.FooterSize.Width, 100.)
    }
```

If you have some deeper nesting, it gets a bit harder.

```
type Page = { FooterSize: Size }
type Document = { Title: string; Page: Page }

let document = { Title = "Fun and Profit"; Page = { FooterSize= Size(10., 10.) } }
```

To update height, now you have to do:

```
let document' = { document  with Page = { document.Page with FooterSize= Size(document.Page.FooterSize.Width, 100.) }}
```

And that goes off screen! There's a [language suggestion for nested record assignment](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/379), which would allow you to do `{ document with Page.FooterSize.Height = 100. }` , but that's still a little ways off.

#### Lenses

```
type Lens<'a,'b> = ('a -> 'b) * ('a -> 'b -> 'a)
```

*Don't worry if this seems confusing! It will become much clearer in time.*

Lenses are the functional equivalent to C#'s property set technology™ (basically `page.FooterSize.Height = 100.` in C#).

They're quite simple, just a pair of getter, setter functions.

```
let getFooterSize (p: Page) = p.FooterSize
let setFooterSize (p: Page) size = { p with FooterSize = size }

let getPage (d: Document) = d.Page
let setPage (d: Document) page = { d with Page = page }

let getWH (s: Size) = s.Width, s.Height
let setWH (s: Size) (w, h) = Size(w, h)
```

Of course, we can get values by simply using the compose right operator:

```
let (w, h) = (getPage >> getFooterSize >> getWH) document
```

But setting doesn't compose.
But with just three simple operators, we can have something very readable:

```
let get (getter, _) = getter
let set (_, setter) = setter

let (>=>) (get_ab, set_ab) (get_bc, set_bc) =
  get_ab >> get_bc,
  fun a c -> set_ab a (set_bc (get_ab a) c)
```

Since our lenses are just pair of getters and setters:

```
let pageL = getPage, setPage
let footerL = getFooterSize, setFooterSize
let sizeL = getWH, setWH
```

That's it. Those are our lenses. We can now compose these lenses with the fish operator (`>=>`) we had defined.

```
let (footer_w, footer_h) = get (pageL >=> footerL >=> sizeL) document
let document' = set (pageL >=> footerL >=> sizeL) document (footer_w, 100.)
```

Of course, you can write a lens in a much shorter form:

```
let pageL : Lens<Document, Page> = 
    (fun d -> d.Page), (fun d p -> { d with Page = p })
```

Comment: This is the best explanation of Lenses I have seen. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, Alan. If you're coming from a C# background, there's always a period of shock. But that will pass soon. Keep at it!